# Can I submit query to Gemini/Bard or other LLM by using an URL shortcut and search engine shortcut with %s url trick?

Tags: shortcuts

User is heavy user of search engine shortcuts in browser. It saves a step of going to a website in step 1. Assume a query like: Suggest 7 day trip itinerary to southern France to some LLM. Can I just type 'llm Suggest 7 day trip itinerary to southern France to some LLM' to browser? (or other shortcut string besides 'llm'.

Answer (score 1):

Bing Copilot does support this. Here's an example URL that can be used to send `Hello Bing`:

```
https://www.bing.com/search?showconv=1&sendquery=1&q=Hello%20Bing
```

The separate queries:

- `showconv=1` automatically opens the chat view
- `sendquery=1` whether or not to automatically send the query
- `q=` is the actual message to send. It must be URL Encoded.

Found by [u/Dyl8Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/Dyl8Reddit) with more details [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/bing/comments/15h9xka/i_figured_out_how_to_start_a_conversation_with/)

Comment: Great ! Now we need the same for Gemini. I will give bounty to answer that shows that.